# fb:feeling FBGraphAction Enum options

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-ios-sdk

Where do I find the Enum option for the `fb:feeling` for a `FBGraphAction`?

I want to set a property (`fb:feeling`) for a Share Dialog (Facebook Open Graph) but I can't find the specific available values. It should be something like: `happy` or `sad`. I would like to have the list with the machine names.

[image]

Big thanks!